# Breakpoints are not working inside the category files

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, objective-c-category

I have a category for UIView and added breakpoints in it. While debugging the control is not coming to those break points. I did make sure

1. It is not in release mode.
2. Breakpoints are not disabled
3. Dwarf with dsym file is enabled under Debug Information Format in build settings.

Have anyone experienced and resolved this?

Comment: Do you have NSLog / print statments in it to make sure the code is reaching that particular part of the code?

Comment: Yes. I have NSLog

Comment: Same problem, is there any solution?